# Newly bought HP Pavilion laptop - bloatware - security risks

Tags: windows, hardening

I’ve recently bought a new HP Pavilion laptop, it came with pre-installed software (bloatware) such as various games and other useless stuff.

When setting up the laptop, i was connected to AIS, which is Thailand foreigner mobile network.

I have immediately took an action and deleted all bloatware except preinstalled HP software.

I’ve already downloaded some Windows auto updates, but i believe this should not be problem, as it is not possible to do MITM attacks on Windows updates.

However, i am concerned about the bloatware.

I know i might be paranoid, but the fact that bloatware comes with security vulnerabilities is well known and i am scared as i do not know whether Thailand AIS mobile network could be compromised and exploiting these security holes in the pre-installed bloatware.

Should i be concerned? Is it possible that i’ve already been infected? Or am i paranoid?

Should i reinstall Windows and start with clean shield without bloatware? What about rootkit/bootkit viruses, i believe that even newly installed Windows would not help in that case.

Comment: Please keep questions to one topic at a time. I have removed the "hardening" parts.

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you if you are compromised. In general, it is better to install the OS fresh on any new machine you buy, especially if it has pre-installed apps. It's just a matter of control.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, i really do appreciate.